# How to give apache permission to write to home directory?

Tags: php, apache

My server is in /var/www/html I have a php script in /var/www/html/fileio_test/io_test.php

```
<?php

$logging = <<< LOG
This is a test
LOG;

$testfile = fopen('/home/djameson/test.txt', 'a'); 
fwrite ($testfile, $logging);
fclose($testfile);

?>
```

When I try to run this script I get

```
Warning: fopen(/home/djameson/test.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in   /var/www/html/fileio_test/io_test.php on line 7

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/fileio_test/io_test.php on line 8

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/fileio_test/io_test.php on line 9
```

How do I let apache write to my home directory? The server runs on fedora 20.

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As your file residing in your Home directory, I would suggest one of following approaches.

1. Give 0777 permission to file itself.

   ```
   chmod 0777 /home/djameson/test.txt
   ```
2. Change Ownership to apache user www-data and give owner-write permission.

   ```
   sudo chown www-data:www-data /home/djameson/test.txt
   chmod 0744 /home/djameson/test.txt
   ```
3. Add your user to www-data group or vice-verse add www-data user to your group. And then group write permission.

   ```
   sudo usermod -a -G www-data djameson
   chmod 0764 /home/djameson/test.txt
   ```

NOTE : I am assuming apache user name & group name is www-data & www-data respectively. You must change accordingly your server apache username/group name.

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Comment: `djameson` is user or group name in `3` ?

Comment: `sudo usermod -a -G mark www-data` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 23):

> By default, Apache on Ubuntu runs as **www-data**.
>
> Let's assume your folder is located in **/var/www/mysite**.
>
> You can do this:
>
> `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/mysite`
>
> `chmod -R og-r`
>
> `/var/www/mysite` After doing this, `www-data` (the Web server) will have
>   full access to the site's files, while other non-root users will have
>   no access at all.
>
> If you wish to allow select users to access the site, you can make the
>   folder group-readable and add those users to the group **www-data**.

[Set correct permissions on your apache files](http://www.linux-noob.com/forums/index.php?/topic/1144-set-correct-permissions-on-your-apache-files/)

Comment: This one is pretty neat and helped and didnt messed up with other settings too Thanks

Comment: Best answer here. Setting 0777 permission is a pretty damn bad idea.

Comment: Works pretty well!

Answer (score 2):

My experience with this has never been good. Anyway, this issue generally has two sides: give apache (or that user) ownership permission, and also tell **selinux** that you are aware of this write request. Try this, it should work:

```
chown -R apache /full-path-to-target-folder/
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /full-path-to-target-folder/
```

Also, ensure that you properly target the specific folder; **not** the whole home directory

Answer (score 0):

In order for this file to be readable for both the user "djameson" as well as the webserver, you need to do 4 things:

1. Add the user apache uses (www-data on most systems) to a user group on your system. You might want to create a new one.
2. Add the user "djameson" to that group as well.
3. Change owner permissons (`chown`)of the file, so that it is owned by the user django and the group you just set up.
4. Make sure the file permissions (`chmod`) allow read permission by the group.

Comment: Well. Create it, then, why don't you.

Answer (score 0):

if some of your files are outside of www directory and you would like to provide access to files outside of apache environment you may use 
chmod -R o+rx

Above would give "other users(also include apache user)" permission to read/execute files