# Creating directory for file upload in PHP

Tags: php, session, file-upload, fileshare

I'm creating a file upload form that asks for a username in file_share.php, then should go to an upload form upload.php that allows users to upload files.

The problem is with the line:

```
`$full_path = sprintf("/home/dfatoki11/uploading/%s/%s", $username, $filename);`
```

When I run the file it says failed to write session data and the error is permission denied. When setting up temp file to store uploaded files what directory do I use and how can I set permissions on the aws/apache web server?

**fileshare.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
  echo $_SESSION['username'];
  ?>

<?php
$myFiles = sprintf("/home/dfatoki11/uploading/%s/%s", $userName, $filename);
$files=scandir($myFiles);

$full_path = sprintf("/home/dfatoki11/uploading/%s/%s", $username, $filename);
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = $finfo->file($full_path);

header("content-Type:" .$mime);
readfile($full_path);
?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
<p>
<label for="file">Choose a file to upload:</label> 
<input name="uploadedfile" type="file" id="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</p>
</form>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
        session_start();
        // Get the filename and make sure it is valid
        $filename = basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
        if( !preg_match('/^[\w_\.\-]+$/', $filename) ){
           echo "Invalid filename";
           exit();
        } 
        // Get the username and make sure it is valid
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        if( !preg_match('/^[\w_\-]+$/', $username) ){
           echo "Invalid username";
           exit();
        } 
        $full_path = sprintf("/home/dfatoki11/uploading/%s/%s", $username, $filename);

              if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $full_path) ){
                 header("Location: file_share.php");
                 exit();
              }else{
                 header("Location: login.php");
                 exit();
              }


?>
```

Comment: check for permission of directory , and be sure the permission of upload directory is 755 or 777 .

Comment: note that you should use 777 just for testing purposes

Comment: use `chmod` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) to change file permission in php.

Comment: cd /path/to/folder
chmod 777 -R /path/to/folder
-R is recursive for the folder and sub folders and sub directories
u should be a sudo doer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to give the user "www-data" permission to your /home folder.
How to do that can be found here:
[How to give apache permission to write to home directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062266/how-to-give-apache-permission-to-write-to-home-directory)