# PHP Implicit Curl File upload work local but not in prod

Tags: php, curl, ftp

When I test this code on my computer everything works fine but in prod, the file uploaded on the remote server is empty. What kind of php/server config could cause this issue?

```
static function implicit_ftp($srcFile, $dstFile, $host, $port = 21, $username = null, $password = null, $acc = null)
    {
        $curlhandle = curl_init();
        curl_reset($curlhandle);
        curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftps://' . $host . '/' . $dstFile);
        curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);
        curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_PORT, $port);
        curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLFTPSSL_TRY);
        curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH, CURLFTPAUTH_TLS);

        $fp = fopen($srcFile, 'r');
        curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
        curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($srcFile));
        curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);

        curl_exec($curlhandle);
        $err = curl_error($curlhandle);
    }
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($err)` return?

Comment: $err is empty when I dump it

Comment: apart from already provided answer, maybe try adding verbose logging to curl: `curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);`

Comment: I tried to add CURLOPT_VERBOSE, nothing changed

Comment: Nothing new in error?

Comment: ok, try changing `curl_exec($curlhandle);` to `$data = curl_exec($curlhandle);` and then dump the `$data` variable (provided the verbose option is still on)

Comment: It seems to be an error with the SSL / TSL "Encountered end of file"

Answer (score 0):

First double-check if the php extension curl is running. For that, simply create an info.php file and Insert the following: `phpinfo()`. Visit the website and use CTRL+F and search for curl.

If curl is enabled, you could be facing a permission issue. Since I don't know what type of web-server you are using, I am just going to assume that it is Apache for now.
You will need write and read permissions. To set these up, have a look at the following thread: [Apache Give Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062266/how-to-give-apache-permission-to-write-to-home-directory)

Since I can see a ftp tag in your thread, you can also use an ftp client to simply right click the folder in which you want to insert your image and go to permissions to apply them from there.

Comment: yes, Curl is installed, we use it everywhere. this is the file generated on the server
-rw-r--r--   1 apache apache    7219 Nov 15 09:44 VVQ-LYNX548332_15-11-2022_094419.xml

Comment: The file appears not to be empty by what you have provided. what is the contents using `less` command or `cat` command? Example: `less VVQ-LYNX548332_15-11-2022_094419.xml`

Comment: sorry, I mean, this is the file I am trying to upload. I wanted to show you the permission.

Comment: Then it does not matter what permission has the file. The target directory also has to have access pernission